# Whats AMFPHP and how do I use it to read binary files?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, binary-data, amfphp

I need a solution to read **raw binary** from any filetype stored on a server.

I heard of AMFPHP but initially got put off since I believed it required admin-access to install the service on the server.

Can I use it to read binary files? Any solution to this would be greatly accepted.

*(No, I tried binary in XML CDATA sections but there are too many 'control' characters that are illegal)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need no privileges to install amfphp, simply put it on a subfolder on your server.

After that you just need to write the php code to read your binary files and use amfphp to pass along those datas to your actionscript code. [Here](http://www.flash-db.com/Tutorials/helloAS3/) is a decent tutorial on amfPhp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AMFPHP services are written in PHP, so it's just a matter of writing a service that reads your binary files and returns the data to the client.

And as you may have discovered, installing AMFPHP doesn't require any special privileges.